# How to multiply columns and add the results?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Assume that a table has two columns named "x" and "y" filled with numbers; for example, x contains the values (1, 2, 3), and y contains (5, 8, 20).

How can I calculate the sum of the products of the columns, i.e. (1 × 5) + (2 × 8) + (3 × 20) = 81?

Comment: You could do `SELECT SUM(x * y) FROM Table`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Siyual notes in the comments, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT SUM(x * y) FROM Table
```

[Here's a live demo on SQLize](http://sqlize.com/ZF8f7y08z2), just to confirm that this does work.

Comment: I used psql before and I know this should work, but now im on Sqlite doing some online database for a project and when i output my answer to variable that contains query answer it says 6... and i cant imagine how...maybe Sqlite syntax is different?

Comment: I have not used Sqlite, but this is *very* basic SQL syntax, and I'd be surprised if it worked any differently there. As the obvious first thing to check, I'd suggest doing "SELECT x, y FROM Table" and checking that it really contains what you expect it does.

Comment: yea u are right, thx i had some problem with primary key, didnt set another column like ID to be my primary key, so that was the problem. Thanks alot =)